# On localhost the file is downloading properly from ftp but not in Ubuntu server

Tags: php, ftp

On `localhost` I tried to get the ftp file from server and the local file is successfully created. But when I'm trying in Ubuntu server it's displaying there was a problem and file is not downloading into server. Here is the code . And code file created in this location `/var/www/html/`:

```php
<?php
// define some variables
$local_file = 'local.csv';
$server_file = 'serverfile.csv';
$ftp_server="ip address";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server)or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
$ftp_user_name="user anme";
$ftp_user_pass="pass";
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
} else {
echo "There was a problem\n";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Please help me to solve this issue, in local host it's working fine but in Ubuntu server local file not creating/downloading.

Comment: What machine is your _Localhost_ and what _Ubuntu terminal_? Are they running the same OS? Has PHP (or web-server) write permission in the directory where you want the file to be saved? Could you get a detailed error message using [`error_get_last()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)?

Comment: Hi Sir, i'm getting this error 
There was a problem Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => ftp_get(): Error opening [file] => /var/www/html/wftp.php

Comment: Please tell help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a permission problem. The directory `/var/www/html` is most likely owned by `root`:

```
mirek@testsrv-ubuntu:/var/www/html$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root   4096 dec 23  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root   4096 dec 22  2015 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  11510 dec 22  2015 index.html
```

The user running PHP must be allowed to write in that directory. If PHP is run by Apache, you need to allow the user `www-data` to write. The following command will list running Apache processes. The username is the first column.

```
mirek@testsrv-ubuntu:/var/www/html$ ps -ef | grep apache
root      1605     1  0 jul20 ?       00:00:16 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1963  1605  0 12:01 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Since `root` is allowed to write anywhere, you can just change the owner of the `/var/www/html` directory to `www-data` and both `root` and `www-data` will be able to write there.

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

More info on file permissions and owners:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-104-5/
- https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: permission for the file
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data        0 Jul 22 10:26 whdfcleads.csv

Comment: @SriP Is that the file you want to write? If you want to create a new one, you need write permission on the directory.

Comment: i want to create at first time, once it's created the file again i have to rewrite the data by running the crons

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data     673 Jul 22 10:31 wftp.php

in wftp.php  this file having code

Comment: But you want to write `local.csv`, right? So change permission of `local.csv`, or if it does not exist, the directory where it should be created.

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     636 Jul 22 11:05 wftp.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data       0 Jul 22 11:04 local.csv

still issue is existed :(

Comment: ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

Please find the solution to this issue

Answer (score 0):

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); is the solution for my issue